# Not able to replace static image in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

below are my settings.py entries.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/eankuls/django-kuls/django_test/assets'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/eankuls/django-kuls/django_test/static/',
)
```

My image is placed as `"/home/eankuls/django-kuls/django_test/static/images/ankur.jpg"`. I executed `"python manage.py collectstatic"` command which created a copy of my image as `'/home/eankuls/django-kuls/django_test/assets/images/ankur.jpg'` and executed perfectly.

Now I am trying to replace this image with `'kuls.jpg'`. I deleted the assets folder. Replaced the `ankur.jpg` with `kuls.jpg` at `'/home/eankuls/django-kuls/django_test/static/images'` and run the `"collectstatic"` command again.

It created the assets folder successfully with `"kuls.jpg"` but upon running the server `"ankur.jpg"` is visible on my browser instead of `"kuls.jpg"`. Older one is not even present any where in my folder structure still it is present in output. Please help.

Please let me know if you need more details additional to my settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is ok and that the problem is coming from your browser.
Clear your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its the height of foolishness :).. I should have done this already..

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us :)